# How to update React component based on user's input?

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, json

I have 2 dropdown lists. First contains options with colors and second has foods. Each of the foods has "color" key in foods.json file. Now, based on user's chosen color I want to update dropdown component containing list of foods, so that it only includes foods that match it.

---

page.js

```js
'use client'

import Dropdown from "./data-import"

export default function HomePage() {
  return (
    <div>
      <Dropdown type="colors" />
      <Dropdown type="food_types" />
    </div>
  )
}
```

---

foods.json

```js
{
    "colors": [
        "red",
        "yellow",
        "green"
    ],
    "food_types": {
        "apple": {
            "color": "red",
            "sweet_scale": "high",
            "skin_edible": "yes"
        },
        "banana": {
            "color": "yellow",
            "sweet_scale": "mid",
            "skin_edible": "no"
        },
        "kiwi": {
            "color": "green",
            "sweet_scale": "low",
            "skin_edible": "yes"
        },
        "tomato": {
            "color": "red",
            "sweet_scale": "mid",
            "skin_edible": "yes"
        },
        "pepper": {
            "color": "yellow",
            "sweet_scale": "low",
            "skin_edible": "yes"
        },
        "cucumber": {
            "color": "green",
            "sweet_scale": "low",
            "skin_edible": "yes"
        }
    }
}
```

---

That's my Data-import.js file so far.

What's missing is getting information about chosen color and then returning dropdown list with only foods that match its color. I've tried doing that with document.getElementbyId() and window.onload, but failed.

```js
'use client'

import foods from '../data/foods.json';

export default function Dropdown({ type, type_id }) {

    var options;
    var types = [];

    if (type == "food_types") {
        //get user's color?
        Object.keys(foods[type]).forEach(function (key) {
            types[key] = foods[type][key].value;
        })

        options = Object.keys(types).map((food) =>
            <option key={food} value={food}>{food}</option>
        );
    } else if (type == "colors") {
        options = foods[type].map((color) =>
            <option key={color} value={color}>{color}</option>
        )
    }

    return (
        <select id={type_id}>
            {options}
        </select>
    );
}
```

Comment: *"I've tried doing that with document.getElementbyId() and window.onload"* - Directly interacting with the DOM in React is almost always the wrong approach.  I see no reason to do that here.  You're missing the single most fundamental piece of React... **state**.  Whatever React tutorial(s) you're using will cover this, you should reference that.  In this case the `HomePage` component would have state values for the current selection of the drop-downs, and would pass state values and setters to the `DropDown` component(s).

Answer (score 0):

You need to look at [state](https://react.dev/learn/state-a-components-memory).
If you use `useState` hook, pass the value and the setter to dropdown as props.